# LaTeX book chapter headings with first/last item remark

Tags: header-footer, books

### Prerequisites

1. `xelatex`, in the shell only.
2. `book` document style

### Goal

The goal is that in the heading of each page where `book` naturally places the chapter name above a horizontal rule, either below that rule or close to it (either on the
recto/verso appropriate side), the label of the first and last item is rendered.
(Think "dictionary")

### Solution

(Edited after reading the comments)

So, it looks like this is a common question. I don't know why I didn't recognize the answers earlier.

There are a few key steps.

#### Use the `fancyhdr` package.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

#### Define new headers

```
\fancyhead[LE,RO] {\rightmark -- \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE] {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
```

#### Define elements with simple marks

So in my MWE, at the start of each `figure` add:

```
\markboth{Alpha}{Alpha}
\begin{figure}[H] 
% ...

\markboth{Beta}{Beta}
\begin{figure}[H]
% ...
```

That results in the *recto* page with header of

`Chapter N     X - Y`

and *verso* page with

`X - Y    Chapter N`

I lost the name of the chapter somehow (I can get chapter number, just not name of the chapter), but I can tinker with it.

Close enough.

### MWE Explanation

MWE below is a book and within a chapter are figures.

Each figure has some property: a label/name, doesn't really matter. But it is a string.
I've used Greek letter names as an example. Treat them as the label.
Each figure has one of these labels.  There are about 1,000 of these figures in the book, spanning 220-240 pages.

So in the MWE, on page 2, under the name of the Chapter, the string would be:

"Episilon - Kappa".

On page 3, where the chapter title would appear (if it did, chapter names appear on the recto pages, only it seems.. Different question for later).

"Lambda - Pi", etc..

And so on.  Each page's header has in the outside margin near the chapter title the X-Y range.

Is there an idiom in LaTeX (or package with the capability) to assist automation of that heading decoration?

Extra credit:  Instead of **each page**, the range X-Y would calculated between span the first label on the *verso* to the last label of the *recto* and the span rendered "X-Y" would appear near the outside margin with the X on *verso* and Y on *recto*.

If it helps, I do have some flexibility in generating the `.tex`.   ALL of the figures are actually rendered from LaTeX that is software generated,  So, if I need to tweak each figure, I can do so when the `.tex` is generated.    In other words, I can insert arbitrary instrumentation into each `figure` with constructs that assist the paging/heading calculation of X-Y range for that *verso* to *recto* span.

Comment if I've left something out that would assist my understanding.

Thank you.

Repo-steps:

```
$ xelatex mwe.tex
```

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolum]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ...
\begin{document}

% ...
\mainmatter
\twocolumn
\chapter{Hook, Line, Sinker}

 % The figure pertaining to Alpha
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Alpha}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Beta
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Beta}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Gamma
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Gamma}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Delta
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Delta}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Epsilon
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Epsilon}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Zeta
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Zeta}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Eta
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Eta}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Theta
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Theta}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Iota
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Iota}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}
 % The figure pertaining to Kappa
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Kappa}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Lambda
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Lambda}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Mu
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Mu}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Nu
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Nu}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Xi
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Xi}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Omicron
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Omicron}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Pi
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Pi}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Rho
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Rho}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Sigma
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Sigma}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Tau
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Tau}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Upsilon
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Upsilon}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Phi
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Phi}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Chi
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Chi}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Psi
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Psi}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

 % The figure pertaining to Omega
   \begin{figure}[H] {\textbf{Omega}}\\ \lipsum[75] \caption{Foo, bar}
   \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Related closely?

Where would I look in the manual(s) for guidance on calculating the first occurrence of some reference/label in a page.

The mini MWE (pesudo-code) would run like this:

```
\newcomamnd{\TestFirstOnPage[1]{%
  % Do something to test if #1 has been on this page yet?
  % Or rather, some code that can test a counter that has the min/max 
  %    value in the given page where it is used? 
  % If so, print winner-chicken-dinner #1
  % else, wompwomp #1
}

% ...
\begin{document}

\TestFirstOnPage{Foo}
\TestFirstOnPage{Bar}
\TestFirstOnPage{Foo}

% ...
\end{document}
```

Renders

```
winner-chicken-dinner Foo
winner-chicken-dinner Bar
wompwomp Foo
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This sounds related to the requirements for headers in a dictionary,  Try looking for questions related to that topic.  Relevant commands might be `\topmark`, `\firstmark` and `\lastmark`,  (Unfortunately, I don't have time at the moment to do such a search.)

Comment: That seems to be the way forward. I don't why I missed it.  Thanks.  I edited the question with a working solution.   Still a minor tweak I need to figure still (name vs number of chapter), but that's downhill from here.